# Css font-family. Отличается на Mac и Windows

Tags: css, mac

Подключаю вот этот веб шрифт https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/d4ff5d995a89c2ffe47cfb729fdca981

Но он отображается по разному на разных системах. Пример
https://prnt.sc/rpbhr6
Слева Виндовс, справа Мак.
Шрифт должен быть "пористый", как на винде, и этого хочет заказчик. В чем проблема и можно ли ее решить?
На айфоне шрифт норм

Comment: Какая версия Safari на маке и на айфоне?

Comment: Точно не знаю, но могу сказать это не в браузере проблема, так как на Маке шрифт одинаковый и на Хроме и на Сафари

Comment: Тогда какая версия мака и iOS?

Comment: Chrome Version 80.0.3987.122 (Officiell version) (64 bitar)
MacBook Pro
macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (18G3020)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Mac и Windows разные системы рендеринга и сглаживания шрифтов. Хотите получить точное совпадение на разных системах - замените "шрифтовой" заголовок картинкой.

Answer (score 0):

На маке это не решило проблему, но на винде пористость можно настроить так:

```
 -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.2px;
```

Еще добавлял такие значения

```
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```